# Chart.js; Chart is not showing time and imported data.

Tags: javascript, php, api, charts, chart.js

I am quite new to programming and expecially javascript.
To learn javascript I was thinking to create a chart using "ticker data" from coinmarketcap. To get the ticker data I created the following function:

```
function golemPrice() {
    //Fetch data
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/golem-network-tokens/?convert=EUR");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $rawData = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

// decode to array
    $data = json_decode($rawData);

//Access array[0] and select value price_eur
    $gntPrice = $data[0]->price_eur;

// show data
    return $gntPrice;
}

?>
```

To put the data into a chart, I was thinking to use chart.js. I created the following chart:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.js"></script>
<script>
    let priceFromFunction = ["<?php golemPrice();?>"];
    let timeFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm";
    let myChart = document.getElementById('golemChart').getContext('2d');
    let lineChart = new Chart(myChart, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Golem chart',

                borderColor: "rgba(80, 164, 245, 4)",
                data: priceFromFunction
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: "time",
                    time: {
                        format: timeFormat,
                        // round: 'day'
                        tooltipFormat: 'll HH:mm'
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Date'
                    }
                }, ],
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Price'
                    }
                }]
            },
        }
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately my chart is not showing the date and no data from the function is added. I tried many different things but now I am out of ideas.

Hopefully you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing echo the function value, try replace this:

```
let priceFromFunction = ["<?php golemPrice();?>"];
```

to

```
let priceFromFunction = ["<?php echo golemPrice() ?>"];
```